# How to pick first day of the week Using AngularJS $locale?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

Does anybody know why in the default locale settings `("en-us")` `$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.FIRSTDAYOFWEEK` is `6` and not `0`? I thought it's sunday and `Date.getDay()` for sunday is `0`...

You can also look it up here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_en-us.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my confusion here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11900